# Export Spring Boot Actuator Metrics using Dropwizard to Jmx or Graphite

Tags: spring-boot, dropwizard, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I want to use Spring Boot `MetricsWriter` to write/export data from my Spring Boot application to a data source of my choice (say - Jmx/Graphite). I can use `JmxReporter`/`GraphiteReporter`, but I guess Spring's abstraction of `Writer`/`Exporter` can play a vital role in terms of data source changes later.

My REST endpoint is annotated with Dropwizard annotations

```
@Timed(absolute=true, name="invokeEndpoint")
public ResponseEntity<Object> callSomeApi() {
   ...
}
```

My configuration class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBootMetrics {

    @Bean
    @ExportMetricReader
    public MetricReader metricReader() {
        return new MetricRegistryMetricReader(metricRegistry());
    }   

    public MetricRegistry metricRegistry() {
        final MetricRegistry metricRegistry = new MetricRegistry();
        return metricRegistry;
    }

    @Bean
    @ExportMetricWriter
    MetricWriter metricWriter(MBeanExporter exporter) {
        return new JmxMetricWriter(exporter);
    }
}
```

I don't see any metrics for endpoint invocation to be collected in Jmx through my jconsole. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only missing piece in this case seems to be to add a `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.MetricsEndpointMetricReader` to your Spring configuration, like for example:

```
   @Bean
   MetricsEndpointMetricReader metricsEndpointMetricReader(MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint) {
      return new MetricsEndpointMetricReader(metricsEndpoint);
   }
```